# How to bind signal of item in QAbstractListModel to handler in delegate of ListView

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qabstractlistmodel

I have a `QAbstractListModel` descendant class with list of instances of my arbitrary type `MyItem` inside. Also I have a `ListView` with model binding to that `QAbstractListModel` descendant.

All I want to do is to bind handler in delegate of `ListView` to the signal of my arbitrary type `MyItem`. Is there any way to do it?

**UPD.** I don't want to bind delegate to signal of a model so when I will have many items all of them will be triggered. I want to notify only one delegate with a signal.

Comment: Emit a signal from the model instead, with `MyItem` (or its index) as a parameter. The model can connect to signals off individual items as it creates them; or the item can simply call a method on the model. The view can connect signals from the model when the model is set.

Comment: I'm trying to omit situation when each delegate should connect to a signal of whole a model and then in handler check if the current signal belongs to it. If I will have a lot of delegates, I want to notify only one, but not all.

Comment: What do you mean, "belongs to it"? One doesn't typically have a separate delegate per item. If somehow you do, then just connect to that item's signal directly, just as you would with any other object.

Comment: You want me to bind to model's signal with index and in delegate check if index of signal and index of delegate match, then execute code for this delegate. That what I meant "signal belongs to the delegate"

Comment: What do you mean by "index of delegate"? A delegate isn't normally tied to a particular index; observe how all methods of, say, `QAbstractItemDelegate` take `QModelIndex` as a parameter. Do you have as many instances of the delegate class as there are items in the model? This would be an unconventional setup.

Comment: Of course it is normally tied to a particular index - http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-models-delegatemodel.html http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-listview.html#delegate-prop - Each item of QAbstractItemListModel is matched with a delegate instance. Or you meant smth different?

Comment: I must admit I've never used `DelegateModel`, or QtQml in general. `QAbstractItemModel` certainly doesn't manufacture a delegate per item. In the "traditional" setup, the delegate belongs to the view, not the model. Note that the class whose documentation you cite does not in fact derive from `QAbstractItemListModel`

Comment: But again, if for whatever reason you do end up with a delegate per item, can't each delegate simply retrieve the corresponding item from the model, and connect to it directly?

Comment: I will not end up with separate delegate per item, sorry. My delegate surely belongs to the view.